# Read Json dynamically and query for values

Tags: c#, json, .net, dynamic

I have a unique problem to solve and I've tried everything I could find with no success.

1. Read Json in to some dynamic or anonymous object.
2. Query the object at runtime with configurable properties.

With simple Json example:

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "FirstName": "Amy",
        "LastName": "Richardson"
    },
    "Address": {
        "Street1": "1234 Main Street",
        "City": "Dallas",
        "State": "TX",
        "Zip": "77555"
    }
}
```

I have been able to read the json into a dynamic in C# and read values as:

`jsonDynamic.Customer.FirstName`

And this works.  The problem I'm trying to solve is the customers would like for me to make this configurable from the database where they can have a configuration value of

`Customer.FirstName`
or
`Customer.LastName`
or
`Address.City`

At runtime I'd read this configuration value and query the json for this property value.  Something like this would be nice.

`jsonDynamic[configValue]`

Where configValue = "Customer.FirstName" to return "Amy"

Any help from someone with this type of exp would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried many examples from different sites and seem to end up with no solution.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need dynamic, just use Parse

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var path = "Customer.FirstName";

    var val = GetValueFromJObject(jObj,path); // "Amy"


public string GetValueFromJObject(JObject jObj, string path)
{
    return  jObj.SelectToken(path).ToString();
}
```